# The Chrome browser opens but does not go to the page

Tags: selenium

The error (s) are

```
C:\Users\kclarke\workspace\Watir>cucumber features
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 9515
[5988:6436:0216/144720:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(146)] Could not read gaming score from assessment results.
[5988:6436:0216/144720:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[5988:6436:0216/144720:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[2636:7124:0216/144735:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(405)] pipe error: 232
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.38.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
```

Chrome Driver (version v2.4.226107 ) installed in path: `C:\Ruby200\bin;C:\Users\kclarke\workspace\bin`

My Code looks like this :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

#@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
#@browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
@browser.goto 'http:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: I added the entire ouput from the execution.

Comment: I am using Chrome : Version 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: No . This is my initial setup. I have spent days trying to resolve this .

Answer (score 1):

First, this has nothing to do with wrong `PATH`, as clearly you can see from the message, ChromeDriver can be started successfully.

Then I'd suggest upgrade your ChromeDriver first before doing anything else, as your version is way out of date. From the  changelog [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt), version 2.4 is 5 months old and the latest is 2.9, which supports Chrome 31-34. (Version 2.4 claims to support Chrome 32, but your Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m now is the latest, which wasn't the one when ChromeDriver 2.4 was released.)

Comment: I downloaded and added version 2.9 of the chrome Driver. Ran the output is below .....

Comment: C:/Users/kclarke/workspace/Watir/features/support/env.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

C:\Users\kclarke\workspace\Watir>[5260:5264:0216/182235:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Comment: The first error is something wrong with your code at `env.rb:24`, please post it. The second error is just ChromeDriver's logging, don't worry about it.

Comment: It works now ! Went thru the code and corrected white space as well as typo's Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi i had the same problem so i downloaded chromedriver 2.9, and even updated the gem, however my ruby selenium keeps on using the old 2.4 version of chromedriver, any idea how to point at the new version?

Comment: @user3233238: Since you're a new user and never accepted any answers before. Just so you know since this answer fixes your issue, you might consider accept it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697)